# Redeclaration of parameters

Tags: java, parameters, static, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

While looking through the Selenium source code I noticed the following in the PageFactory:

```
public static <T> T initElements(WebDriver driver, Class<T> pageClassToProxy) {
  T page = instantiatePage(driver, pageClassToProxy);
  initElements(driver, page);
  return page;
}

public static void initElements(WebDriver driver, Object page) {
  final WebDriver driverRef = driver;
  initElements(new DefaultElementLocatorFactory(driverRef), page);
}
```

What is the benefit of having the following line?

```
final WebDriver driverRef = driver;
```

Wouldn't it have made sense to just make the parameter final, and then passing that along to the next method without declaring the new reference?

Comment: Yep.  That would've made more sense.

Comment: Maybe the developer was unaware of the `final` modifier? lolz

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question, I highly suspect it would be compiled out of the bytecode by the jvm as a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer is that setting `final` on a variable and only use it as an argument to a function is completely useless. In the `DefaultElementLocatorFactory` constructor, the variable related to the input argument can be freely reassigned, since it is a copy of the original reference.

P.S. ... unless of course, as suggested by the OP, the input argument is instead declared `final`.

Comment: I must point out I feel quite lame providing this answer, but I don't see anything else to say and someone had to, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

The best thing I can come up with (under the assumption that the selene devs have more than a basic understanding of how java works - which I think is given):

Presumably before there was a `DefaultElementLocatorFactory` class, the method used an anonymous inner function and when the code was refactored some parts were just overlooked.

Comment: This is why I asked, I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing out on some JVM bug or magic which was occurring which simply hadn't been commented on.

Comment: @Scott In fact final or no final will generate exactly the same bytecode, except that the JLS allows the inlining of final variables in certain situations. That's basically how closures work for anonymous classes, was first added so that `if(DEBUG) {]` could be optimized away and is in general a horrible to find source of bugs. But none of that applies to your given code.

Comment: I did give this +1, but found no evidence to the claim that it was utilized by an anonymous inner function (I looked through the commit history on Google code).  However, my guess is that is a likely possibility.